# Change the Default Access Permission of a Google Sheets made with googlesheets4 with R

Tags: r, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api, googlesheets4

I would like to change the default permissions of a google sheets file to `anyone with the link can read`

```
weekly_fight <-
  googlesheets4::gs4_create(
    paste0(
      two_weeks_ago_monday,
      "-",
      two_weeks_ago_sunday,
      "/",
      last_monday,
      "-",
      last_sunday,
      "_Weekly Report Google Analytics My Site GA4|UA+Top SKU+COUPON"
    ),
    sheets = list(
      Weekly_Traffic_site1 = week_on_week_2,
      Weekly_Traffic_site2 = week_on_week_2_im,
      Ecommerce_Performances_site1_IT = top_products_sold_last_week_ua_site1_EN,
      Ecommerce_Performances_site2_IT = top_products_sold_last_week_ua_site2_EN,
      Coupon_site1 = count_coupon_site1,
      Coupon_site2 = count_coupon_site2
    )
  )


googlesheets4::gs4_browse(weekly_fight)

metadata <- googlesheets4::gs4_get(weekly_fight)

url_doc <- metadata$spreadsheet_url
```

I can read and browse the file as creator but when I send the link with the script via email with the gamilR package to my team they cannot access it as I need to manually update the permission in the file

Is there a way to change the default access to the file with the googlesheets4 package or the Drive API without manual intervention?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First off to set permissions on a file you would need to go though the Google drive api.  Changing the permissions is out of scope for the google sheets api.

This can be done with the [permissions.create](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions/create) method in the google drive api.

Second `anyone with link` can read only works through the web UI you cant create that link via the any api drive or sheets.

[image]

You could set the file to public they anyone should be able to access it.

Comment: Thank you @daimto, If I understand correctly I can use the `permission.create` method with the ID of the sheet file and use the methods listed [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/permissions#resource) to parse the request

Comment: yes just set it to public.   then anyone will be able to access it.   Just do a file.get on the file id and there should be a webview link that they will be able to open in a web browser window.   Sorry i am not an R dev so i cant help with code.

Comment: thanks to your suggestion It works now, I have found a wrapper to facilitate this task within the [googledrive R](https://googledrive.tidyverse.org/index.html) package that has a function to change the permission of a file, you just need to provide it with a file ID or URL : `googledrive::drive_share_anyone(file = as_id(id))`.